# ЧПУ в социальной сети.

Tags: mod_rewrite, вконтакте

Привет ещё раз.
Как работает mod_rewrite в контакте?
там все страницы в один уровень: vk.com/что-то 
http://vk.com/feed  
http://vk.com/im 
http://vk.com/videos3216933.
http://vk.com/nickname. 
то есть страницы себя названы одним словом. других людей(кроме главной) - слово айди. страницы профиля других просто слово, которое сами выбираем. Как такое реализовать?
Думаю это сделано так: сначала правила переадресации для страниц типа feed, video, im, потом правила для страниц других людей, которые вычленяют из урла id пользователя, а потом уже, когда все правила кончились, любой урл засчитывается как главная страница пользователя. И, разумеется, нельзя называть свою страницу типа feed. Я прав?

Comment: можно конкретные роуты направить на нужные контроллеры, хотел что-то еще добавить к этому комменту (типа: а ид-юзеров на другие), но смысла не вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, на уровне mod_rewrite идет просто редирект в любом случае на индекс, а там уже при помощи PHP происходит парсинг.

таки да, можно и так как вы описали: последовательно прогнать через несколько функций.